# List item inside dropdown box

Tags: php, css, yii

i have a database generated list and i want it to display inside a dropdown box. I am currently experimenting with YII, and i do not know how to achieve this. I tried and failed a couple of times already. My hair is getting thinner. Heh.

Here is what it looks like now;

[image]

Below is my code;

```
public function taskLangMenu() {
    $items = array();
    $langs = $this->languages();
    foreach ($langs as $code => $name)
        $items[] = array(
            'label' => $name,
            'url' => aUrl('/base/setting', array('name' => 'language', 'value' => $code)),
            'active' => $code == app()->language,
            'linkOptions' => array('name' => $code, 'class' => 'langLink'),
        );
    cs()->registerScript(__CLASS__, 'jQuery(".langLink").live("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            method: "post",
            success: function() {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });');

    return $items;

}
```

this is to display the dropdown list:

```
if (count($this->param('languages')) > 1)
        $items['language'] = array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items' => wm()->get('base.helper')->langMenu(),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'pull-right'
            )
        );
```

i tried below code to try and display the drop down list, it doesnt work.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('taskLangMenu',1, $langs);
```

Comment: +1 for the hair comment. I felt your pain. Now what is your current output ?

Comment: thanks 4 that. heh. currently its listing as two separate buttons. i want the two buttons as a drop down list

Comment: would love to see the generated html actually...could be a css issue in my view

Comment: added a picture @AdityaSaxena . :)

Comment: will you try to do print_r($langs) because i think $langs variable is not populating data, If data is available in $langs, Please paste here the print_r output

Comment: $langs has data inside it. below is what is available when print r . @sarvesh 

    Array ( [en_us] => English (US) [ms_my] => Malay )

Comment: i changed echo CHtml::dropDownList('taskLangMenu',1, $langs); to echo CHtml::dropDownList('langLink',1, $langs); and it displays the thing inside drop down. now the problem is it wont refresh the page to the correct language

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/M8zAq/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>English (US)</li>
    <li class="active">Malay</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    position:relative;
}

li{
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#EEE;
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    height:25px;
    bottom:-35px;
}

li.active{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('li.active').hover( function(){
    $(this).siblings('li').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).siblings('li').hide();
});
```

Comment: i want to do it in Yii.

Comment: Okay..I guess my answer should be downvoted..apologies for me overlooking it. I'll give it a shot anyway, and will let you know if I'm at all able to find anything